# Custom animated transition - view in/view out

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, transition, uiviewanimation

I have a custom transition written in Swift where the dismissed view goes out as the presented view comes in from the side.

Now I want this same effect, but I want the presented view to come in from the top and the dismissed view go out at the bottom.

My code looks like this:

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning){

    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)
    let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)

    let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container.frame.width, 0)
    let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container.frame.width, 0)


    if self.presenting == true{
        toView?.transform = offScreenLeft
    }else{
        toView?.transform = offScreenRight
    }

    container.addSubview(toView!)
    container.addSubview(fromView!)

    let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {

        if self.presenting == true{
            fromView?.transform = offScreenRight
        }else{
            fromView?.transform = offScreenLeft
        }
        toView?.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        }, completion: { finished in

            // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

    })
}
```

I thought this would be easy, as my logic tells the way to do this is to change from "width" to "height" in the toView, and fromView, but this does not work, and just creates the same effect as before, but it seems to skip one empty (black) view.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the desired effect would be appreciated.

The buggy code:

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning){

    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)
    let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)

    let offScreenUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container.frame.height, 0)
    let offScreenDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container.frame.height, 0)


    if self.presenting == true{
        toView?.transform = offScreenDown
    }else{
        toView?.transform = offScreenUp
    }

    container.addSubview(toView!)
    container.addSubview(fromView!)

    let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {

        if self.presenting == true{
            fromView?.transform = offScreenUp
        }else{
            fromView?.transform = offScreenDown
        }
        toView?.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        }, completion: { finished in

            // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

    })
}
```

Comment: what is your current code for top to bottom transition? the above code looks like its for sideways transition.

Comment: @rakeshbs it's exactly the same but I've replaced the "width" with "height" everywhere it appears in the code.

Comment: Can you please replace the code. You have to show the buggy code. Not the one which is working

Comment: @rakeshbs Yes, it has now been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still trying to translate in the X Coordinate. Try doing the translation in the Y coordinate.

```
let offScreenUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,container.frame.height)
let offScreenDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-container.frame.height)
```